# aws codepipeline approval / review stage not building latest commit but building every single commit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an angular site which I build with `ng build`. 
My pipeline looks like this: `source code -> Build -> Staging -> Approval -> Prod`

I have an issue where if 2 commits are pushed to the repo, let's say commit 1 (c1) and commit 2 (c2), the approval step will behave like follows:
It will approve c1 which will flow to the Prod stage where we do another build like this `ng build --prod` (to minify js files) and then the approval stage will then automatically kick off a second build for C2.

`Expected behavior`:
I was expecting the approval to only grab the latest commit in this case let's say C2 was the latest, and only build C2, since C1 got superseded by C2.

Here's how my approval stage looks like in the template:

```
    Stages:
    - Name: Source
      Actions:
        - Name: Source
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Source
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CodeCommit
          Configuration:
            RepositoryName: !Ref ProjectName
            BranchName: master
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: checkout
          RunOrder: 1
          RoleArn:someRole
    - Name: Dev
      Actions:
      -
        Name: staging
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Version: 1
          Provider: CodeBuild
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProject
        RunOrder: 1
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: checkout
        OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: buildOutput

    - Name: Approval
      Actions:
      - 
        InputArtifacts: []
        Name: pushToProd
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Approval
          Owner: AWS
          Version: '1'
          Provider: Manual
        OutputArtifacts: []
        Configuration:
          NotificationArn: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:########:myApprovalTopic
          ExternalEntityLink: http://myWebsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html
          CustomData: Approving changes to Prod
        RunOrder: 1

    - Name: Prod
      Actions:
      -
        Name: Prod
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Version: 1
          Provider: CodeBuild
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProd
        RunOrder: 1
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: checkout
        OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: OutputArtifactsProd
```

Anyone have any idea why my approval stage will NOT pick up the latest commit and only build to PROD only ONCE upon clicking that approval/review button? Instead it queues up the commits and after you click the approval button, it build all queued up commits in this case C1 and C2 instead of ONLY BUILDING THE LATEST COMMIT :(

Answer (score 1):

Exactly one active pipeline execution can occupy a stage. When the pipeline execution corresponding to `C1` enters the `Approval` stage, that stage is locked until you either reject or approve the pipeline execution and `C2` will wait for the `Approval` stage (either the pipeline execution corresponding to `C1` fails or exits the stage). If you want to let later builds catch up, reject the earlier build that is waiting for approval.

You should place the staging action and approval action in the same stage. This lets you approve exactly what you tested. Otherwise different pipeline executions can occupy each stage and you're not necessarily approving what you tested.

Here's an example (based on your example) that combines the `Dev` and `Approval` stages:

```
    Stages:
    - Name: Source
      Actions:
        - Name: Source
          ActionTypeId:
            Category: Source
            Owner: AWS
            Version: 1
            Provider: CodeCommit
          Configuration:
            RepositoryName: !Ref ProjectName
            BranchName: master
          OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: checkout
          RunOrder: 1
          RoleArn:someRole
    - Name: Dev
      Actions:
      -
        Name: staging
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Version: 1
          Provider: CodeBuild
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProject
        RunOrder: 1
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: checkout
        OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: buildOutput
      - 
        InputArtifacts: []
        Name: pushToProd
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Approval
          Owner: AWS
          Version: '1'
          Provider: Manual
        OutputArtifacts: []
        Configuration:
          NotificationArn: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:########:myApprovalTopic
          ExternalEntityLink: http://myWebsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/index.html
          CustomData: Approving changes to Prod
        RunOrder: 2

    - Name: Prod
      Actions:
      -
        Name: Prod
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Version: 1
          Provider: CodeBuild
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildProd
        RunOrder: 1
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: checkout
        OutputArtifacts:
          - Name: OutputArtifactsProd
```

Comment: Thanks when you say, `You should place the staging action and approval action in the same stage` what do you mean? Please i'm new to aws and learning as much as I can. Does my pipeline above NOT place both staging and approval in same stage? Do you perhaps have an example or a github link for reference?

Comment: The YAML in your question declares one action per stage. What I'm suggesting is that you declare two actions in a single stage. For example: you could remove the `Approval` stage and, instead, add the `pushToProd` action to the `Dev` stage.

Comment: When you say `You should place the staging action and approval action in the same stage` could you please adjust my pipeline and show me how it'd look with your suggested changes? I'm a bit new to AWS and learning as much as I can but struggling to piece together all this stuff

Comment: I updated my answer to include your example pipeline with two edits (combine the `staging ` and `pushToProd ` actions into a single `Dev` stage and set the `pushToProd` action to have a run order of 2, i.e. after the `staging ` action).

Comment: Thank you will try that; when you say ` If you want to let later builds catch up, reject the earlier build that is waiting for approval`, so if there were 10 commits that queued up, i'd have to click that reject button like 9 times in order to only pass through the very last commit that we care about? My hope was that all the commits would flow through staging/Dev then eventually wait for approvalToProd; and when I click approve, it only grabs the latest commits since that commit is the latest code? Why do I care about all previous commits out of 10? when I could just approve the 10th one?

Comment: And in a real world situation, if we've queued up 100 commits before pushing to prod, then i'll tell people to click approve 100 times or reject 99 times then approve 1 time in the case 100 commits have queued up? There just seems like there would be a flag/feature of codepipeline to set and say only deploy latest commit after I click 'approve' what do you think?

Comment: CodePipeline will batch changes between stages (a later pipeline execution supersedes an earlier pipeline execution), so you'd have the first pipeline execution to reject (unlock the stage) and the last pipeline execution to approve. Why doesn't CodePipeline supersede in a stage? There's no way to know if you've started manually testing something that you intend to approve and deploy ahead/separate from other changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the "pushToProd" action to be  the first action in the "Prod" stage
and disable transitions to the Prod stage. 
This way, even though you had 100 commits before pushing to prod, You will only need to enable stage transition on the 100th commit and  only the latest revision runs through the prod stage and approve the action only for the revision that's going in to production.